# Automated Software deployment through SCCM 2012 using wmi

Tags: powershell, deployment, wmi, sccm

I was been looking for an option to automated deployment(Installation) of software in the client machines using SCCM 2012 by making calls to WMI classes through code. I have found the following URL 
   http://www.sepago.de/e/david/2012/03/17/microsoft-configuration-manager-2012-and-powershell-ae-create-deployments

But this only advertises the packages available for install. I want something that would allow me to actually install the software. Hope my query was clear.

Regards
Tiklu

Answer (score 0):

```
Start-CMApplicationDeployment

Start-CMPackageDeployment

Start-CMTaskSequenceDeployment
```

And with the `-DeployPurpose<DeployPurposeType>` parameters set it to `Required`

You can't do it with `Start-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to suggest the [Total Software Deployment](http://www.softinventive.com/total-software-deployment/) software for remote software installation. This tool is a new alternative to SCCM. It may be a bit less functional in the current version, but I beleive that it will develop into something bigger soon.