# How to trigger installation of User-Available Application purely through WMI or other code without having to use Software Center?

Tags: wmi, sccm

In SCCM, WMI class CCM_Application in ClientSDK does not list User-Available (Target = User Collection, Purpose = Available) Applications unless you Install them manually from the Software Center once, and hence you cannot trigger Installation ("Install" method of the "CCM_Application" class) of an application that has been made available to a user but has not yet been installed through the Software Center. Is there any way we could trigger the installation of such Application from the client machine using WMI or other code without actually having to go to the Software Center for the first time? (which otherwise, defies the purpose of ClientSDK IMO).

I do realize that there is a procedure that is followed behind the scenes whenever the deployment is made available to the user, the Policy gets downloaded (or enforced) to the client machine only once the installation is triggered through the Software Center and not before that. But all these steps of discovering and installing the User-Available Application, is it possible to do that from the client machine just like the Software Center, WITHOUT ever having to use the Software Center? There has to be a way.

EDIT:
Our purpose is not to automate the process or to use purpose = required. What we are trying to achieve is to trigger the installation of User-Available Applications externally (not automatically) through WMI without having to go to the Software Center, just like we can Install/Uninstall Device-targeted Applications though the Methods exposed in the WMI class CCM_Application without having to use Software Center at all. We can also do the same for User-Available apps as well, but only once they have been installed through the Software Center, because then they get added to the CCM_Application just like the other apps and you can install/uninstall them without using the Software Center. Why can't we perform the first initial detection of User-Available Apps and install them for the first time as well? If SDK allows us to do all the above functionality, why are we forced to use Software Center for just one step? There should/must be a way.

Can anyone refer an SCCM expert to this Question? Anyone from Microsoft who actually have solution to this?

I have already read many long blogs on the internet related to this query but none seem to have figured it out.

Related Questions:

1. [CCM_Application User available software missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276451/ccm-application-user-available-software-missing)

(unsolved)

2. [Automated Software deployment through SCCM 2012 using wmi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056088/automated-software-deployment-through-sccm-2012-using-wmi)

This question has been answered but the objective there is different. It simply creates and starts the deployment of a software from the Configuration Manager. What I am trying to achieve is to Install the already deployed software (which is Available and hence not automatically installed), right from the client machine and not the server. Just like the Software Center does.

Comment: Just as info, from MS point of view there is probably no "purpose" of ClientSDK as you imagine it. If you want to automatically install something you use required deployments if you want the user to do it you use available, that is MS point of view. So the automation of a process that was by choice defined as manual is not important. That is not to say that it is impossible I have not looked into it that much, but I fear that when features are added/changed no one is there to guarantee that ClientSDK keeps up with them. That is no priority for MS (most wmi stuff isn't even documented properly)

Comment: Our purpose is not to automate the process or to use purpose = required. What we are trying to achieve is to trigger the installation of User-Available Applications externally (not automatically) through WMI without having to go to the Software Center, just like we can Install/Uninstall Device-targeted Applications though the Methods exposed in the WMI class CCM_Application without having to use Software Center at all... 
(continued in next comment)

Comment: (continued)...
We can also do the same for User-Available apps as well, but only once they have been installed through the Software Center, because then they get added to the CCM_Application just like the other apps and you can install/uninstall them without using the Software Center. Why can't we perform the first initial detection of User-Available Apps and install them for the first time as well? There should/must be a way.

Comment: I didn't want to argue that this should not be possible (it is very hard to use these limited comments to talk about complex situations) just to warn you that not a lot points to MS seeing WMI as a means for you to do everything that can be done via UI. (just like e.g. triggerschedule in wmi uses different rights than in UI) I just mentioned it so you maybe can already prepare yourself to look in different directions because there are things that just don't work via WMI and no one seems to know why. But as I said I am not sure it cannot be done in your case, maybe someone knows a way

Comment: As indicated in an answer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/169898/ccm-application-client-wmi-class-available-softwar.html there might be a difference if it is deployed to a user collection vs a device collection (this is not the same as installing per user/device which is a different setting (so a application deployed to a machine can still be installed per user)). Is this the case in your scenario?

Comment: Some comments here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/83256/info-of-user-targeted-application-missing-under-sc.html also seem to indicate that it could be related to the user (and it's elevation status) used for the query

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your time. Syberdoor. 
Really appreciate your time and efforts mate.

Regards.